# How does the g++ implementation handle this situation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002082/typecasting-with-virtual-functions).

Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    int i;
    virtual void Func() = 0;
};

class C : public B
{
    public:
    char c;
    void Func() {}
};

int main()
{
    C* pC = new C;
    A* pA = (A*)pC;
    std::cout << "pC == " << std::hex << pC << "\n";
    std::cout << "pA == " << std::hex << pA << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

With Visual Studio 2010, the output is (on my machine):

```
pC == 002DEF90
pA == 002DEF94
```

(this is explained by the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002457/140367) of the question).

With g++, the [output is](http://ideone.com/PbZ4z):

```
pC == 0x96c8008
pA == 0x96c8008
```

So, the question is, how does the implementation of g++ handle this case? What makes the addresses the same when `C` should have a vtable? (I know that this is an implementation detail, don't say that :) I'm interested in this implementation detail out of curiosity).

Comment: The g++ may generate vtable for all class type. In this way the casting is more safe than in Visual C++. Just imaging: what happens if you get a `void *` pointer of class B and you cast it back to class A. g++ generate bigger code but safer for "tree" (typical) inheritance. As I remember intel compiler do it similarly.

Comment: @Naszta: That would break the "don't pay for what you don't use" rule. I just think the vtable is stored somewhere else (maybe at the end). The -S as Rob says will provide the answer.

Comment: What is your working hypothesis?

Comment: @Skizz: you don't pay. A typical class has a pointer for its vtable. There is only one instance of the vtable is generated for all of the instance of the class. The vtable load to the memory could be optimized, so just the necessary vtables are stored in memory and just one for all class instances.

Comment: Useful [link](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/). And [connected question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70682/what-is-the-vtable-layout-and-vtable-pointer-location-in-c-objects-in-gcc-3-x). [One more link, may be the best one.](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html#vtable)

Comment: @Naszta, this is a C++ ABI proposal for Itanium architecture. Is this what g++ uses?

Comment: I am not sure. But I don know any reason why it should work differently on other platforms. I try to look for a x86 version, too.

Comment: Adding any field to base class 'A' changes this behavior. It seems, g++ feels free to place base classes prior to vtable pointer only if they are empty. Probably, it is related to empty base class optimization.

Comment: @Naszta: If a class has no virtual functions then there is no need to have a vtable. Class A in the question has no virtual functions. You wouldn't expect a vtable for an instance of A.

Comment: I found a link: [but it is true for gcc 3.2 only(?)](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.2/c++-abi.html).

Comment: @Skizz: true. In this case class A has no virtual table. class B will have and the pointer of virtual table will be at the top of class A data. In this way the address of the objects will be the same, and the address of class B will be correct for class A, too.

Comment: I feel that I'm a bit off-topic since nobody mentioned this obvious fact yet: `sizeof(A)` returns `1` in gcc 4.5.2, so it can't contain a vtable pointer (unless my computer has an 8-bit address space :) ).

Comment: @enobayram: check my previous comment. (Addressed to Skizz.)

Comment: @Naszta I agree with your comment, I just wanted to give another perspective.

Comment: so does anyone know *why* the vptr gets put at the beginning, rather than after the `A` subobject? Couldn't an implementation save some pointer adjustment/thunking overhead by simply putting the vptr in a different location?

Comment: @wolfgang: It is a trade-off: if you put the vptr at the beginning of the layout, you need some adjustment when casting to `A`, but there is no offset to be applied when performing virtual method calls. On the other hand, if the vptr is elsewhere (after the `A` subobject, for instance), you don't need any adjustment when casting, but you need to apply an offset to access the vptr. And all this becomes even more complex when you introduce multiple inheritance and worse, virtual inheritance.

Comment: @wolfgang, the vtable pointer goes at the beginning specifically to avoid pointer adjustment.  The typical scenario is not casting from one type to a subtype (or vice versa).  The typical scenario is calling virtual functions on one type.  If you put the vtable pointer first, you skip the cost of offsetting the object pointer when calling virtual functions.  i.e. "objPtr->vptr" maps to just "*objPtr" instead of "*(objPtr + N)".

Comment: If this conversation protracts beyond a few more comments, please consider moving it to [chat].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much fiddling, I finally remembered something.

The **Empty Base Optimization**.

As soon as `A` gets a member, the result change. However as long as it has none, the compiler is not required to generate a real layout for `A`, all that matters is to guarantee that each `A` "object" will have a different address from any other `A` object.

Therefore, the compiler simply use the address of the `B` subobject (which inherits from `A`) as a suitable address. And it turns out that `B` and `C` have the same address (first base + both having virtual methods).

On the other hand, if `A` has a member OR if the first member of `B` is a `A` (there are other conditions), then the **EBO** cannot apply any longer and you'll notice a jump in the addresses.